# Partial day event retrieval with google calendar api

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying to retrieve an event that has a start and end time. When I try to retrieve an event for a particular date, while all day events are returned, events with a start and endtime are not returned.

```
# Path to your service account key JSON file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = SecretPath

# Function to get the events from a specific calendar on a given day
def get_calendar_events(calendar_id, date):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'])
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    start_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z")
    end_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT23:59:59Z")

    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id, timeMin=start_date, timeMax=end_date, singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    return events

date = datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 7)
test = get_calendar_events(calendar_id = CalendarID, date)
print(test)
```

Updated code

```
import datetime
import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def CheckForOutShabbos(Thursday=None):
    
    calendar_id = 'nf3bm4osamd12s7hm5601gensc@group.calendar.google.com'
    events = get_calendar_events(calendar_id, Thursday)
    print("events: ", events)
    if not events:
        IsOutShabbos = False
        print("No events found on Thursday", Thursday, ".")

    return IsOutShabbos

Thursday = datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 7)
IsOutShabbos= CheckForOutShabbos(Thursday) #The problem is here. No event is found on 2023-09-07, yet there is an event on that date.
```

The Calendar can be found [here](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/embed?height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&ctz=America/Chicago&src=bmYzYm00b3NhbWQxMnM3aG01NjAxZ2Vuc2NAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&src=bGJrdmg3a2twb29nOGg1ODk5OTZ1cmQ4MTRAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&src=NW5wY3M4ZW9lbXY3YnZoZnRsbDkwbnFsamdzdWEyaTZAaW1wb3J0LmNhbGVuZGFyLmdvb2dsZS5jb20&color=%23D81B60&color=%23F09300&color=%237CB342&showTitle=1&showCalendars=0&showTabs=0)

I tried removing the time factor (Ie. T00:00:00Z). I assume the issue is that for some reason it is only checking for all day events since all day events are returned without any problems.

Comment: About `while all day events are returned, events with a start and endtime are not returned.`, after I created 2 events of `all day events` and `events with a start and endtime`, when I tested your showing script using `date = datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 7)`, I confirmed that both event types are returned. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your current situation. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation?

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated the question to better provide the necessary info

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing your sample calendar. From your sample calendar, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated question and your sample Calendar, I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to the timeZone. When my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
start_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z")
end_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT23:59:59Z")
```

#### To:

```
start_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00-05:00")
end_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT23:59:59-05:00")
```

- When I tested your script by reflecting this modification using your provided calendar, one item with the event title of "Out-Shabbos" could be retrieved.

Comment: That worked, Thank you so much. Do you know if that will work with any TimeZone?

Comment: @Cortex8938 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Do you know if that will work with any TimeZone?`, I think that when the timeZone is changed it is required to modify `05:00` of `%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00-05:00`. In this answer, from your provided calendar, I could know the calendar's timeZone. By this, I could propose this modification. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.